# React: Trying to set state via useEffect using local JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a functional component that uses `useState` to set the `mtvData` state (via `setMtvData`).

However, I'm trying to call `setMtvData` in `useEffect` so that the `mtvData` state will have the json data and that json data will be passed to the `Chart` component.

But so far the Chart component just gets an empty string:

```
import Chart from './Chart.js';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import myjson from './data/myjson.json'

export default function App() {

  const [mtvData, setMtvData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMtvData([...myjson]);
  },[])

  return (
     <Chart data={mtvData} />
  )

}
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `./data/myjson.json` file and whats done in your `Chart` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting the state on mount instead of initializing the state with your json?

```
import Chart from './Chart.js';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import myjson from './data/myjson.json'

export default function App() {

  const [mtvData, setMtvData] = useState([...myjson]);

  return (
     <Chart data={mtvData} />
  )

}
```

Comment: It does not work for this?

Comment: Why doesn't it? There is no reason to set the state on mount but render the component initially thats using the state?

Comment: Right. It is better. but meanwhile, seem it should not give her an empty string! because the value is set in the second render.